# Can't get tag's content with xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to get the 'Shipping Weight' value(i.e 4.65 pounds) from amazon page, here is the part involved(from [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0018RSEMU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0018RSEMU)):

```
<div class="a-row a-spacing-top-base">  
  <div class="a-column a-span6">  
    <div class="a-row a-spacing-base">  

        <div class="a-section table-padding">  
          <table id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1" class="a-keyvalue prodDetTable" role="presentation">  

                      <tr>  
                          <th class="a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry">  
                          Shipping Weight  
                          </th>  

                          <td class="a-size-base">   
                        4.65 pounds (<a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/seller/shipping.html/ref=dp_pd_shipping?_encoding=UTF8&amp;seller=ATVPDKIKX0DER&amp;asin=B0018RSEMU">View shipping rates and   policies</a>)  
                        </td>  
                        </tr>                            
                        ......
```

I code like this:

```
from lxml import html   
import requests  
headers = {'User-Agent': '...'}  
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)  

doc = html.fromstring(page.content)  
XPATH_WEIGHT = '//th[contains(text(),"Shipping Weight")]/following-sibling::td/text()'  
RAW_WEIGHT = doc.xpath(XPATH_WEIGHT)
```

after running, it returns nothing. What's the problem? With the same syntax, I can get other tag's text correctly. so confused here.

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to create `doc` or indicate which library you're using? I used lxml and it worked for me with the exact same code in your question.

Comment: I used your updated code and it worked. Perhaps you want to add one last line with `print(RAW_WEIGHT)` to see the result?

Comment: yeah, i tried 'print(RAW_WEIGHT)' and the result is '[ ]' (empty list).   do u use the exact url(https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0018RSEMU) to run my code?

Comment: I just realized it's a table element. so i tried with:  XPATH_WEIGHT = '//table[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]', but the result is still empty.

Comment: The content you want to extract is created dynamically(with Javascript) on the page. That's why xpath doesn't work as expected. You need to use something else than `requests`, smth that can load the page with dynamic content - maybe Selenium.

Comment: well, change from xpath to BeautifulSoup, i get the content successfully. though still don't know why xpath doesn't work.